# How to load & call a VBScript function from within C++?

Tags: c++, windows

We have customers asking for VBScript functions to be called when particular actions occur within our product. I've been trying to research the Windows Scripting technologies but I'm having difficulty finding exactly what I need. Hopefully some of you can help.

Our product is a native C++ Windows product. The customer would specify a VBScript file, which we would load, and whenever a particular event occurs, we'd call a particular function in the VBScript and let it do its thing. We may provide objects within the script's namespace for it to access information about our product as well.

I found some information on MSDN about the IActiveScript interface, and some related things, but cannot find any examples of instantiating a COM object that implements this interface for VBScript.

I know that PowerShell would probably be a better option for this these days, but our customers are stuck in a lot of legacy systems and VBScript is what they know.

Any help you can provide (links or otherwise) would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a good question, but might be better suited for StackOverflow.  This site is really for more subjective topics.  IActiveScript is, imo, the right direction for you to investigate.

Answer (score 16):

I've put together a "Hello World" IActiveScript C++ ATL console application that:

- Define `CSimpleScriptSite` class

  - Implement `IActiveScriptSite` interface (mandatory)
  - Implement `IActiveScriptSiteWindow` interface (optional)
  - Minimum implementation with most functions implemented with a dummy stub
  - Has no error handling. Consult MSDN [IActiveScriptError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/b17d71fw(v=vs.94).aspx).
- Use `CoCreateInstance` a new `IActiveSite` object

  - Create instances of both `VBScript` and `JScript`
  - Link the `IActiveSite` to `IActiveScriptSite` using `IActiveSite::SetScriptSite`
  - Call `QueryInterface` to get an `IActiveScriptParse` interface
  - Use `IActiveScriptParse` to execute `VBScript` or `JScript` code
- The sample:

  - Evaluates an expression in `JScript`
  - Evaluates an expression in `VBScript`
  - Runs a command in `VBScript`

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <activscp.h>

class CSimpleScriptSite :
    public IActiveScriptSite,
    public IActiveScriptSiteWindow
{
public:
    CSimpleScriptSite() : m_cRefCount(1), m_hWnd(NULL) { }

    // IUnknown

    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)();
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)();
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject);

    // IActiveScriptSite

    STDMETHOD(GetLCID)(LCID *plcid){ *plcid = 0; return S_OK; }
    STDMETHOD(GetItemInfo)(LPCOLESTR pstrName, DWORD dwReturnMask, IUnknown **ppiunkItem, ITypeInfo **ppti) { return TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND; }
    STDMETHOD(GetDocVersionString)(BSTR *pbstrVersion) { *pbstrVersion = SysAllocString(L"1.0"); return S_OK; }
    STDMETHOD(OnScriptTerminate)(const VARIANT *pvarResult, const EXCEPINFO *pexcepinfo) { return S_OK; }
    STDMETHOD(OnStateChange)(SCRIPTSTATE ssScriptState) { return S_OK; }
    STDMETHOD(OnScriptError)(IActiveScriptError *pIActiveScriptError) { return S_OK; }
    STDMETHOD(OnEnterScript)(void) { return S_OK; }
    STDMETHOD(OnLeaveScript)(void) { return S_OK; }

    // IActiveScriptSiteWindow

    STDMETHOD(GetWindow)(HWND *phWnd) { *phWnd = m_hWnd; return S_OK; }
    STDMETHOD(EnableModeless)(BOOL fEnable) { return S_OK; }

    // Miscellaneous

    HRESULT SetWindow(HWND hWnd) { m_hWnd = hWnd; return S_OK; }

public:
    LONG m_cRefCount;
    HWND m_hWnd;
};

STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) CSimpleScriptSite::AddRef()
{
    return InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRefCount);
}

STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) CSimpleScriptSite::Release()
{
    if (!InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRefCount))
    {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }
    return m_cRefCount;
}

STDMETHODIMP CSimpleScriptSite::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject)
{
    if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IActiveScriptSiteWindow)
    {
        *ppvObject = (IActiveScriptSiteWindow *) this;
        AddRef();
        return NOERROR;
    }
    if (riid == IID_IActiveScriptSite)
    {
        *ppvObject = (IActiveScriptSite *) this;
        AddRef();
        return NOERROR;
    }
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    // Initialize
    CSimpleScriptSite* pScriptSite = new CSimpleScriptSite();
    CComPtr<IActiveScript> spJScript;
    CComPtr<IActiveScriptParse> spJScriptParse;
    hr = spJScript.CoCreateInstance(OLESTR("JScript"));
    hr = spJScript->SetScriptSite(pScriptSite);
    hr = spJScript->QueryInterface(&spJScriptParse);
    hr = spJScriptParse->InitNew();
    CComPtr<IActiveScript> spVBScript;
    CComPtr<IActiveScriptParse> spVBScriptParse;
    hr = spVBScript.CoCreateInstance(OLESTR("VBScript"));
    hr = spVBScript->SetScriptSite(pScriptSite);
    hr = spVBScript->QueryInterface(&spVBScriptParse);
    hr = spVBScriptParse->InitNew();

    // Run some scripts
    CComVariant result;
    EXCEPINFO ei = { };
    hr = spJScriptParse->ParseScriptText(OLESTR("(new Date()).getTime()"), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, SCRIPTTEXT_ISEXPRESSION, &result, &ei);
    hr = spVBScriptParse->ParseScriptText(OLESTR("Now"), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, SCRIPTTEXT_ISEXPRESSION, &result, &ei);
    hr = spVBScriptParse->ParseScriptText(OLESTR("MsgBox \"Hello World! The current time is: \" & Now"), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0, &result, &ei);

    // Cleanup
    spVBScriptParse = NULL;
    spVBScript = NULL;
    spJScriptParse = NULL;
    spJScript = NULL;
    pScriptSite->Release();
    pScriptSite = NULL;

    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

A version of the above code can be found here:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/RunScriptDemo

Comment: I did a Delphi translation of your code in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160714/426242

Answer (score 3):

`IActiveScript` and related interfaces work very well.  I use them in my product exactly the same way you have described.  Some of out customers write their own VBScript and JScript scripts to analyze and update application data before it gets posted to a database.

You use `CoCreateInstance()` to instantiate `IActiveScript`, like you would any other COM object.  You would then call its `QueryInterface()` method to obtain an `IActiveScriptParse` interface for loading snippets of scripting code, and then you update the `IActiveScript`'s state to execute the code.

You can add custom objects to the script by implementing `IDispatch`-derived classes and then passing them to the engine using `IActiveScript::AddNamedItem()` and an `IActiveScriptSite::GetItemInfo()` callback.

There are examples of `IActiveScript` usage available on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks, though this is basically what I already understood. Note that I said I found this information on MSDN but wasn't able to find examples. Thanks for telling me there are examples but not pointing to any. (Richard's answer provided this for me)